# Rails Simple Form <form> tags not wrapping around controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have created a partial using Simple_form in Ruby on Rails 4, but when I render the page the form tags in the partial do not wrap around the controls, so when I click on the submit button, the form does not post.

Here is the HTML source of the partial rendered in the browser. You will notice that the controls are not inside the closing form tag.

```
<tr data-id="4">
<form id="edit_social_platform_4" class="simple_form edit_social_platform" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" data-remote="true" action="/social_platforms/4" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
<td>
<div class="control-group string required social_platform_name">
</td>
<td>
<div class="control-group url optional social_platform_url">
</td>
<td>
<div class="control-group integer optional social_platform_user_id">
</td>
<td>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Social platform" name="commit">
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code for the partial in rails:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@social_platform, remote: true) do |f| %>

    <td><%= f.input :name %></td><br/>
    <td><%= f.input :url %></td><br/>
    <td><%= f.input :user_id %></td><br/>
    <td><%= f.button :submit %></td>

<% end %>
```

Below is the code for the controller update method that is being called. This does not running presently.

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @social_platform.update(social_platform_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @social_platform, notice: 'Social platform was successfully updated.' }
        format.js {}
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the update.js.erb file that renders the partial onto the page:

```
$('tr[data-id=<%= @social_platform.id %>]').replaceWith("<%=j render 'social_platforms/social_platforms', social_platform: @social_platform %>");
```

Below is the code on the view which the partial interacts with:

```
<table class="table socialPlatformTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Url</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="social-platforms">
  <% @social_platforms.each do |social_platform| %>
      <tr data-id="<%= social_platform.id %>">
        <td><%= social_platform.name %></td>
        <td><%= social_platform.url %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_social_platform_path(social_platform), remote: true %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', social_platform, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the `<form>` element that you try to declare directly inside a `<tr>` element which is forbidden.

You have only two choice :

- wrap the `<form>` around the whole table

  ```
  <%= simple_form_for(@social_platform, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <table>
    ....
    </table>
  <% end %>
  ```
- put it inside a single table-cell

  ```
  <table>...
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <%= simple_form_for(@social_platform, remote: true) do |f| %>
        ...
      <% end %>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

Actually, there's no way (afaik) to wrap a form around several (but not all) table cells. (And if there's one, I'd be happy to know it)